# Field Validation in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a login page and a registration page. Both were validating smoothly. When I added the membership to the login controller the login page stopped validating the fields however according to my  code it is just popping a message that login failed. Below are my action and view. Any idea why it is not validating knowing that I have the same code in the registration view and its validating.

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignIn(tbl_User user)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserEmail, user.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserEmail, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Common" });
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Msg"] = "Login Failed";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                TempData["Msg"] = "Login Failed "+e.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

**View**

```
@model BOL.tbl_User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Login</h2>
@if (TempData["Msg"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        @TempData["Msg"].ToString()

    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn","Login",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us the exact error displayed?

Comment: There is no error it is just not validating although its reaching the validation code